# Teams winning games despite issuing numerous walks

Tags: baseball, statistics, mlb

How many times has an MLB team won a game after issuing 12 or more walks?

Answer (score 1):

A team that has issued 12+ walks, and won the game has occurred in **171 games**.

The ten most recent:

| Team | Date | Season | BB | @ | Opp | Result | IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HOU | 2023-08-06 | 2023 | 12 | @ | NYY | W 9-7 | 9 |
| HOU | 2021-07-11 | 2021 | 14 |  | NYY | W 8-7 | 9 |
| PIT | 2021-04-13 | 2021 | 13 |  | SDP | W 8-4 | 9 |
| WSN | 2020-09-11 | 2020 | 12 |  | ATL | W 8-7 (12) | 12 |
| HOU | 2020-07-31 | 2020 | 12 | @ | LAA | W 9-6 | 9 |
| ARI | 2019-03-29 | 2019 | 12 | @ | LAD | W 5-4 (13) | 13 |
| MIN | 2018-05-12 | 2018 | 12 | @ | LAA | W 5-3 (12) | 12 |
| CHW | 2016-06-01 | 2016 | 13 | @ | NYM | W 2-1 (13) | 13 |
| SDP | 2016-05-14 | 2016 | 12 | @ | MIL | W 8-7 (12) | 12 |
| BOS | 2015-08-28 | 2015 | 12 | @ | NYM | W 6-4 (10) | 10 |

The most walks issued in a win is 18 walks (accomplished twice)

| Team | Date | Season | BB |  | Opp | Result | IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BAL | 2004-07-02 | 2004 | 18 | @ | PHI | W 7-6 (16) | 16 |
| DET | 1920-09-17 | 1920 | 18 |  | BOS | W 14-13 (12) | 12 |

The full list: https://stathead.com/tiny/Iopw9

**If you want to include games that are only 9 innings or less, then it's 85 games.**

The most walks in a 9-inning games is 16 walks (done in three games)

| Team | Date | Season | BB |  | Opp | Result | IP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SLB | 1948-06-21 | 1948 | 16 |  | PHA | W 9-8 | 9 |
| WSH | 1932-05-03 | 1932 | 16 |  | NYY | W 5-4 | 9 |
| PHA | 1913-07-12 | 1913 | 16 | @ | DET | W 16-9 | 9 |